# get image and display through php script

Tags: php, image

i notice some webpage display images using php scripts. how do i do that and wats the benefit?
forexample: http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yp/r/kk8dc2UJYJ4.png

Comment: You need to draw a picture on php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why showing images through PHP might be useful:**

- Being able to control/restrict access to the images in a complex way (e.g. not just by http auth, ip, referer etc.).
- Being able to dynamically modify images before they are displayed (watermarks for example)

**How you do that:**

Send the appropriate header for whatver image type (e.g. `header('image/png');`) you want to show and then output the raw image data, e.g. using `readfile()`